# Mask for an array in the same shape

Tags: python, numpy

Array2[:,0] contains array1 row indexes, array2[:,1] contains array1 element value. I want to get mask same shape as array1 in vectorized way.

```
array1=
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

array2=
[[0 1]
 [1 3]
 [1 5]
 [2 7]
 [2 9]]
```

Code:

```
array1 = np.arange(9).reshape(-1,3)
array2 = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2)
array2[:,0]=[0,1,1,2,2]

print(array1[array2[:, 0]] == array2[:, 1,None])
```

Result I get:

```
[[False  True False]
 [ True False False]
 [False False  True]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

The result I want to get:

```
[[False  True False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True False]
```

**Edit:**
The loop solution looks like this:

```
mask=np.zeros_like(array1)
for (y,x) in array2:
    mask[y,(np.where(array1[y,:] == x))] = True
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me why you expect it to be in the shape of `array1`. If you perform `A[B]`, you get an array in the same shape as `B` where you perform a "mapping", and convert each element `x` in `B` to `A[x]` so to speak, hence conceptually it does not make much *sense*.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the *semantics* are of the expected result. Why is the first element `False` in that column? What do you want to compare with what?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added an example of a loop that does what I would like to achieve,I hope it is simpler to understand now because it is difficult to describe in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a mapping back:

```
array1 = np.arange(9).reshape(-1,3)
array2 = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2)
array2[:,0] = [0,1,1,2,2]

xs, ys = np.where(array1[array2[:, 0]] == array2[:, 1,None])

mask = np.zeros_like(array1, dtype=bool)
mask[array2[xs,0], ys] = True
```

This gives us for the given sample data:

```
>>> mask
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]])
```